# gnu make - assert specific command line tools are available

Tags: gnu-make

In a makefile, how would I make sure that certain tools like `gcov`, `lcov`, `g++` are available before executing any other targets?

I want to gracefully fail with

> `gcov/lcov/g++` not available

.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
TOOLS := gcov lcov g++

$(foreach TOOL,$(TOOLS),\
    $(if $(shell command -v $(TOOL)),,\
        $(error Cannot locate $(TOOL) on PATH)))
```

This assumes you're using a POSIX shell obviously.